# Probability density function with indicator function

Tags: probability

Given the function

$$ f(x) = 2 \mathbb{I_{\Delta}(x,y)}$$
$$ \Delta = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1]\ ; 1 \leq x + y \leq 2  \}$$

i want to calculate the probability density function and tried a few approaches like:

$$ \Delta = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1]\ ; y \geq 1 -x , y\leq 2 - x \}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2 dx dy = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{1-x}^{2-x} 2 dx dy $$

This didn't work out. Has somebody a idea how to set the limits?

Greetings

Comment: Try sketching out the region..  You'll see the upper bound on the $x$ in the double integral is incorrect

Comment: Thanks, it worked out with the boundary 1-x and 1.